# How to get the key value of a JSON object matching another given value?

Tags: javascript, json

i have this JSON:

```
var projects_array = new Array(
{name:"myName1", id:"myid1", index:1},
{name:"myName2", id:"myid2", index:2},
{name:"myName3", id:"myid3", index:3},  

);
```

I need to get the "index" value of the object matching an specific "id" value. So if my "id" is "myid1" y would get "1".

here is part of my code:

```
 var myid = $(this).attr('id'); //this is the id value

projects_array.map(function (proj) {
    if (proj.id == myid) {
        return proj   // returns Undefined  
    } 
   });
```

Finally, I need to assign that value in a variable to use it later, THANKS :)

Comment: Code tip: Never use `new Array()`. Instead, use array literals: `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @minitech, I got this advise before from SO but why, can you give some idea ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera: It's shorter, it's a little more efficient, it's standard, and people can replace `Array` to mean whatever they want it to mean. Plus, there's the fact that `new Array(5)` won't give you `[5]` but rather `[,,,,]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're selecting the index successfully, but when you return the value, it goes into a new array ("maps" there if you will).  Try something like this:

```
var myproj; 
var myindex;
projects_array.map(function (proj) {
    if (proj.id == myid) {
        myproj = proj;
        myindex = proj.index;
    } 
});
```

Comment: It worked perfectly.. Thank you guys :) I really appreciate all answers and tips!